# How to expand Material UI accordion on mouse over

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to expand Material UI accordions by mouse hover. But I can't see any prop which could be useful. I checked `onMouseOver`, `onMouseEnter` but when its fired closes the accordion. I would simpler for user to avoid over-clicking. I've also add some css parts `"&:hover"` to const Accordion, but without succses.

```
const Accordion = withStyles({
    root: {
        border: '1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125)',
        boxShadow: 'none',
        '&:not(:last-child)': {
            borderBottom: 0,
        },
        '&:before': {
            display: 'none',
        },
        '&$expanded': {
            margin: 'auto',
        },
    },
    expanded: {},
})(MuiAccordion);
const AccordionSummary = withStyles({
    root: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
        borderBottom: '1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125)',
        marginBottom: -1,
        minHeight: 30,
        '&$expanded': {
            minHeight: 30,
        },
    },
    content: {
        '&$expanded': {
            margin: '12px 0',
        },
    },
    expanded: {},
})(MuiAccordionSummary);
const AccordionDetails = withStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        padding: theme.spacing(2),
    },
}))(MuiAccordionDetails);
export default function CategoryList(props) {
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState('panel1');

    const handleChange = (panel) => (event, newExpanded) => {
        setExpanded(newExpanded ? panel : false);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {props.categories.map(category =>
                <Accordion
                    square
                    expanded={expanded === category.label}
                    // onChange={handleChange(category.label)}
                    onMouseMove={handleChange(category.label)}
                    >
                    <AccordionSummary
                        expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon fontSize={"small"}/>}
                        aria-controls="panel1d-content" id="panel1d-header">
                        <Typography>{category.label}</Typography>
                    </AccordionSummary>
                    <AccordionDetails>
                        <CategoryItem category={category}/>
                    </AccordionDetails>
                </Accordion>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

jklkjlk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are pretty close but you don't want to open or close the Accordion on `onChange` or `onMouseMove` handlers, but rather `onMouseOver`.

I did a minimum reproducible example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicaccordion-material-demo-forked-8y1bs?file=/demo.js)

Basically I changed the callback to

```
  const handleChange = (panel) => {
    setExpanded(panel);
  };
```

`+` Added a callback onMouseLeave for the Accordion container `<div>` (to reset the expanded value) and called the handleChange onMouseOver the `Accordion` so:

```
<div onMouseLeave={() => {handleChange("");}}>
  {categories.map((category) => (
    <Accordion
      square
      expanded={expanded === category.label}
      onMouseOver={() => handleChange(category.label)}
    >
    ...
```

`onMouseLeave` callback from the container `div` you can also call `handleChange("pannel1")` (instead of `handleChange("")`) if you want that to be opened when the mouse is not hovering over any category element, or even ignore that part completely if you are fine with leaving the last hovered `Accordion` expanded.

PS: If you create a minimum reproducible example yourself in the future it would make the life of people who can help way easier :)

Comment: Works, now it's easy :D Thanks a lot for your help.  I've got a little glitch effect in my app but as I think I can handle it.

Comment: You're welcome! Also replacing `onMouseOut` with `onMouseLeave` (in the div) should help with the glitch :) I will edit in the answer as well.